# How to avoid using Distinct or Group By in the following SELECT query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Usually, I don't use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` but in the following query, I need to have it because if I don't, it multiplies the results.
I want to get all the users that have at least 1 order.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT us.* 
FROM dbo.users us 
JOIN dbo.orders o ON us.id = o.userId
```

Is it possible to avoid using `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` here?

Answer (score 1):

I would ask you, why you do not want to use distinct or groupby?

If your goal is high performance, I would use something like this:

```
;with cteUserIdsWithOrders as (
  select userId 
  from dbo.orders
  group by userId
)
select us.*
from dbo.users us
inner join cteUserIdsWithOrders o on o.userId = us.userId
```

Comment: Highly unlikely to make a jot of difference to performance. The optimizer is clever enough to transform `distinct`, `group by` versions, your pre-grouped version, and `exists` version between each other and decide which is faster. The query plan will be exactly the same

Comment: @Charlieface: Really? And on all versions of MSSQL servers? :-)

Comment: AFAIK that has been the case since at least 2005, the compiler really isn't that stupid. Please demonstrate a *simple* case of two tables where this is not so

Comment: See here for example https://www.sql.kiwi/2020/05/pulling-group-by-above-join.html and here https://www.sql.kiwi/2019/06/apply-versus-nested-loops-join.html and here https://sqlperformance.com/2018/02/sql-plan/row-goals-part-2-semi-joins